# Grouping neighbor points based on field sum in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, fields-attributes, grouping, summarizing

I have about `14,000` points. These points have a specific field `"time"`, an integer value, mainly between `1`, `2` or `3`.

**I would like to** split these `14,000` points into groups based on the `"time"` field totalling up to `1,000` hours between the neighbours.

So some groups may have `700` points and others may have `500` or whatever it takes to add up the `"time"` field value to `1,000`.

Comment: Could you share a few lines of your table to make the problem clearer?