# Clustering based on eqaul populations

Tags: qgis, clustering, population, grouping, spatial-cluster

I have a map of a city that is divided into 65 sectors (building lots in purple, sector boundaries in red):

[image]

In my shapefile of building lots, I have an attribute that is the total population within each lot (usually between 1 and 5).

Within each sector, I would like to create compact clusters of population size 50. Is there a plugin or tool in QGIS that can do this?

Comment: Grouping features so that the sum of their populations (or another attribute) meets a specified value, is not a simple task. I've seen similar questions, and either the solution was a custom python function, or the question went unanswered.

Comment: ...for example: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/123297/81764 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/290501/81764

Comment: Tell me how you want to cluster points, for example: create 50 points evenly or unevenly within the sector, or 1 point should correspond to 1 sq. Km area or ...